# Proof of the delta method

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

The classical, well known delta method states the following:
If $\sqrt{n}(X_{n}-\theta)\overset{law}{\longrightarrow}N(0,\sigma^{2})$. Then the following holds:
$\sqrt{n}(g(X_{n})-g(\theta))\overset{law}{\longrightarrow}N(0,\sigma^{2}(g'(\theta))^{2})$ for any function $g$ satisfying the property that $g'(\theta)$ exists and is non-zero valued. 
The key step, proving this result, is the following expression:
$g(X_{n})=g(\theta)+g'(\overline{\theta})(X_{n}-\theta)$ for some intermediate value $\overline{\theta}$ with $X_{n}<\overline{\theta}<\theta$. 
What exactly ensures the existence of such a $\overline{\theta}$? It should follow using Taylor's theorem, but I am not able to argue rigorously.

Comment: Mean value theorem?

Comment: @Chappers
So the argument, given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Proof_in_the_univariate_case is wrong?

Comment: Second sentence of that section starts "To begin, we use the mean value theorem [...]"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All that is needed is the differentiability of $g$ at the single point $\theta$; the intermediate value theorem and $\overline\theta$ are not needed.  Recall that "$g$ is differentiable at $\theta$" means that the limit $\lim_{h\to0} (g(\theta+h)-g(\theta))/h$ exists; we give its value the name $g'(\theta).$  Now define the function $r$ by setting $r(h) = (g(\theta+h)-g(\theta))/h - g'(\theta)$ if $h\neq 0$ and $r(0)=0$.  What we know about $r$ is more-or-less *only* that $\lim_{h\to0} r(h)=0.$

But now we have a degree 1 "Taylor approximation": $$g(\theta+h) = g(\theta) + g'(\theta)h + hr(h)$$ just by unrolling the definition of $r$, where we know $r(h)\to0$ as $h\to0$.  Apply this to $h=X_n-\theta$, and multiply by $\sqrt n$ to get $$ \sqrt n (g(X_n)-g(\theta)) = g'(\theta) \sqrt n(X_n-\theta) + \sqrt n (X_n-\theta) r( X_n-\theta).$$

Now Slutsky's theorem kicks in: $\sqrt n (X_n-\theta)$ is *tight* (or $O_P(1)$, if you will) and it multiplies $r(X_n-\theta)$, which converges in probability to $0$, so the product converges to 0 in probability.

The "secret sauce" is that the proof of a degree 1 Taylor approximation amounts to no more than a recitation of the definition of differentiability at the  point of expansion.  Unlike higher degree Taylor approximations, where stronger hypotheses and arguments are needed.

Comment: Is there anywhere in the delta method that says $X_n$ has to converge to $\theta$? (and what type of convergence is necessary?)

Comment: @darkgbm The standard delta method hypothesis is that $\sqrt n (X_n-\theta)$ converges in distribution to a Gaussian. This already implies $X_n$
converges to $\theta$ in probability. Of course in applications one might know more. Such as, usually $X_n$ is a sample average of iid finite-variance summands. In such a case, $X_n\to\theta$ almost surely, and in $L^2$, as well.

Comment: To show that $X_n$ converges to $\theta$ in probability, would it suffice to define $Y_n = 1/n$, which converges to $0$, then multiply $Y_n$ on both sides of $\sqrt{n}(X_n - \theta)$ and the Gaussian and use Slutsky's Theorem to conclude that $X_n - \theta$ converges in distribution to $0$, and since convergence in distribution to a constant implies convergence to probability, we are done? Or is there another more straightforward way?